# rendering Excel data into Webmatrix

Tags: excel, webmatrix

I am trying to read and bind Excel into a webpage and here is my initial code. When I run it in browser, all it does is display the code but not execute it. Here is the code saved as chtml:

```
@{

}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Excel Read Test</title>
</head>
<body>    
        string ExcelFile = Server.MapPath("App_Data/Pending_Requests.xls");
       string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + ExcelFile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString)) 
            { 
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand()) 
            { 
            cmd.Connection = conn; 
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [EAST]"; 
            conn.Open(); 
            OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
            GridView1.DataSource = dr; 
            GridView1.DataBind(); 
            conn.Close(); 
            } 
            }
   </body>
```

How can I execute this code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code tries to bind the data to a GridView, but they are only available in [Web Forms](http://www.asp.net/web-forms). The cshtml files are a different development model known as [Web Pages](http://www.asp.net/web-pages). WebMatrix is designed for developing Web Pages. When you write code in Web Pages, you have to use [Razor syntax](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/intro-to-web-pages-programming). The Web Pages equivalent to a GridView is the WebGrid. This is how to get your code working in the cshtml file:

```
@{
     var connString = "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|Pending_Requests.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";
     var provider = "System.Data.OleDb";
     var sql =  "SELECT * FROM [EAST$]";
     var db = Database.OpenConnectionString(connString, provider);
     var data = db.Query(sql);
     var grid = new WebGrid(data);
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Excel Read Test</title>
</head>
    <body>    
       @grid.GetHtml()
    </body>
</html>
```